# Find the creator of a file in c

Tags: c, linux

I tried the `stat()/lstat()` function, `readdir()` and `getpuid()`, but these metadata only ever shows the *owner* of a file, what function do I use to get the *creator* of a file?
I think the owner and creator of a file are often identical but dont have to be as the owner can be changed.
google search provides endless pages of how to get the owner of a file, but I didnt manage to find how to get the user name of the creator.

Comment: The Operating System does not keep track of that information.

Comment: Does any OS's filesystem keeps track of original creator?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @जलजनक I cannot tell for every filesystem ever, but the most common filesystems do not keep that kind of information.

Comment: Here's the relevant [man-page for inotify](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).